# using fseek to insert string before last line

Tags: php, fwrite, fseek

I am trying to write a very basic registration module for blueimp.net's AjaxChat. I have a script that writes to the user config file.

```
$userfile = "lib/data/users.php";
$fh = fopen($userfile, 'a');
$addUser = "string_for_new_user";
fwrite($fh, $addUser);
fclose($fh);
```

But I need it to insert `$addUser` before the very last line, which is `?>`

How would I accomplish this using fseek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *always* know that the file ends with ?> and nothing more, you can:

```
$userfile = "lib/data/users.php";
$fh = fopen($userfile, 'r+');
$addUser = "string_for_new_user\n?>";
fseek($fh, -2, SEEK_END);
fwrite($fh, $addUser);
fclose($fh);
```

To further enhance the answer: you're going to want to open your file in mode `r+` because of the [following note](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) regarding `fseek`:

> **Note:**
>
> If you have opened the file in append (a or a+) mode, any data you
>   write to the file will always be appended, regardless of the file
>   position, and the result of calling fseek() will be undefined.

`fseek($fh, -2, SEEK_END)` will place the position at the end of the file, and then move it backwards by 2 bytes (the length of `?>`)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is using the [SplFileObject class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) (available as of PHP 5.1).

```
$userfile = "lib/data/users.php";
$addUser = "\nstring_for_new_user\n";
$line_count = 0;

// Open the file for writing
$file = new SplFileObject($userfile, "w");

// Find out number of lines in file
while ($file->valid()) {
   $line_count++;
   $file->next();
}

// Jump to second to last line
$file->seek($line_count - 1);

// Write data
$file->fwrite($add_user);
```

I haven't tested this (I can't on the computer I'm using right now) so I'm not sure if that works exactly like that. The point here is really the cool [seek()](http://php.net/splfileobject.seek) method of the SplFileObject which can seek by line rather than how fseek() seeks by bytes.