# How to insert string before last line?

Tags: php, insert, line

I saw [using fseek to insert string before last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763822/using-fseek-to-insert-string-before-last-line) this question, but this isn't solving my problem. I not use "?>" tag. Php version PHP 5.4

```
example line1
example line2
//i need insert here
lastline $eg};
```

My code is working but this is adding empty lines after all lines :

```
  $filename = 'example.php';   
  $arr = file($filename);
  if ($arr === false) {
      die('Error' . $filename);
    }
array_pop($arr);
file_put_contents($filename, implode(PHP_EOL, $arr));
/// I'm deleting last line here


$person = "my text here\n";
file_put_contents($filename, $person, FILE_APPEND);
$person = "andherelastline";
file_put_contents($filename, $person, FILE_APPEND);
//and then add again here
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of function [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)? Under the "Return Values" section it clearly states: *"Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, **with the newline still attached**."*. The extra rows you get are added by `implode(PHP_EOL, $arr)`. Pass the empty string (`''`) as the first argument to `implode()` and the extra rows will vanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$file = "tmp/saf.txt";
$fc = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fc)) {
    $buffer = fgets($fc, 4096);
    $lines[] = $buffer;
}

fclose($fc);

//open same file and use "w" to clear file 
$f = fopen($file, "w") or die("couldn't open $file");

$lineCount = count($lines);
//loop through array writing the lines until the secondlast
for ($i = 0; $i < $lineCount- 1; $i++) {
    fwrite($f, $lines[$i]);
}
fwrite($f, 'Your insert string here'.PHP_EOL);

//write the last line
fwrite($f, $lines[$lineCount-1]);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: I tried that but forever loop :( And earsing all lines in my text file

Comment: I can't test the code right now since I'm on my mobile but I edited the code.

Comment: This is strange, this code works for me. Are you sure you got the updated code without using splfileobject?

Answer (score 0):

fseek solution in case your files are HUGE

```
$f = fopen('filename', 'r+');
fseek($f, -1, SEEK_END);

// skip spaces and empty lines at end of the file
while (in_array(fread($f, 1), [" ", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\v", "\0"], true)) {
    fseek($f, -2, SEEK_CUR);
}

// move position indicator right before last content line
$lineLenth = 0;
while (fread($f, 1) !== PHP_EOL) {
    fseek($f, -2, SEEK_CUR);
    $lineLenth++;
}

// backup old content
$lastLine = fgets($f);

// move position indicator again since fgets() moved it back to the line end
fseek($f, -$lineLenth - 1, SEEK_CUR);

$newContent = 'Data to be insert' . PHP_EOL . $lastLine;

fwrite($f, $newContent);
fclose($f);
```

tested with php 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Until you need to implement file locking or contend with enormous file sizes, then just get the content, use a regular expression to find the new line character before the last line, inject the new line, then save the file.

```
$filename = 'example.txt';
$new = 'your new text';
file_put_contents(
    $filename,
    preg_replace(
        '/\R(?=.+$)/',     // match last occurring newline sequence followed by: one or more non-newline characters before the end of the string
        '\0' . $new . '\0', // inject the new text with same newline sequence already used in file
        file_get_contents($filename)
    )
);
```