# fseek(): stream does not support seeking

Tags: php, laravel

Read the .txt file and get the last line of the text file, the function that I used is commented below

```
function read_last_line (){

      $line = '';
      
      $f = fopen('localpath\data.txt', 'r');
      $cursor = -1;
      
      fseek($f, $cursor, SEEK_END);
      $char = fgetc($f);
      
      /**
       * Trim trailing newline chars of the file
       */
      while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r") {
          fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
          $char = fgetc($f);
      }
      
      /**
       * Read until the start of the file or first newline char
       */
      while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r") {
          /**
           * Prepend the new char
           */
          $line = $char . $line;
          fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
          $char = fgetc($f);
      }      
      echo $line;
      }
```

While Executing the above code, I get the `fseek(): stream does not support seeking`, Need a solution to resolve the issue.

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) it states that not all streams are seekable and that you should handle this in your code. You may try using SplFileObject instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763822/using-fseek-to-insert-string-before-last-line)

Comment: Not suitable for handling large files, but waaay simpler than what you're trying to do: `$lastLine = end($lines = file($filePath,  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All forms of seeking is not supported and will fail in some cases.

For more detail check documentation
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php